# How to update _index value to make it indexName_{currentDate} using index template?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to create index template which will help me to update *index field value from indexName to indexName*{current_date}.

I found one solution using processors but it's not working for index template,

```
"processors" : [
    {
      "date_index_name" : {
        "field" : “timestamp”,
        "index_name_prefix" : “evidence-“,
        "date_rounding" : "M"
      }
    }
  ]
```

My current indexName is "evidence", I have to make it "evidence_{currentDate}".
Can somebody suggest ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using ingest pipeline?

```
{
    "script": {
      "description": "Set index based on `payload_ts` field",
       "lang": "painless",
      "source": """
        long today = new Date().getTime();
        long payloadTs = ctx['payload_ts'] ;
        
        LocalDate payloadDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(payloadTs).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate currentDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(today).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

        if(payloadDate.isBefore(currentDate)){
          ctx['_index'] = ctx['_index'] + '-' + payloadDate +'-' + '000001';  
        }
      """
      }
    }
```